# No auth cookie set on response with signalr .net client

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, cookies, signalr, signalr.client

I've been following the cookie authentication method from http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/security/hub-authorization and with a asp.net mvc4 project running on localhost it works prefectly fine. I do get the authCookie back in the client.

However, when I publish my asp.net mvc4 project to my host and try to authenticate to that host it doesn't give my any cookies back.

Is this a cross domain cookie issue? Is this approach even possible?

Comment: You haven't given us enough info to diagnose from

Comment: Is the app using the same transport in your computer than in the server? Which operating systems have each?